# How to typecast from MULTIPOLYGON to MULTIPOLYGONM (force XY multipolygon into XYM)

Tags: postgis, convert

I need to merge several databases, where the destination table has a constraint checking for MULTIPOLYGONM in the geometry column.

At some source tables, the geometry column is in the XY form (MULTIPOLYGON), others have the correct XYM form (MULTIPOLYGONM).

How can I force MULTIPOLYGON into MULTIPOLYGONM? Is this what ST_Force_3DM is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like ST_Force_3DM alone is not enough for an "INSERT FROM SELECT", but this worked for me:

```
ST_AsEWKT(ST_Force_3DM(the_geom))
```